# Openlayers Geolocation getPosition sometimes undefined

Tags: javascript, openlayers

this might be a silly question but I have tried everything and I am completely lost. I have the following code.

```
while (k<whileDis){
    var current_pos = geolocation.getPosition();
    console.log(current_pos);
    
    var imbiss_pos = [features[k].getProperties().long, features[k].getProperties().lat];

    var calc_dist = getDistance(current_pos, imbiss_pos);
    console.log(calc_dist)
    if (calc_dist <= distance){
        console.log(String(features[k].getProperties().rating)+"keep")
        tempDis.push(features[k])
    }
    k++
}
features = tempDis
```

The idea is that I have my current position and that of a foodstand and I want to caluclate the distance between them. Now if I reload my page it works fine. But if I return to the front page the `geolocation.getPosition()` is undefined (despite geolocation being defined).
My assumption is that for some reason the first time around other stuff that is being loaded delays the execution of the lower part for enough that the `geolocation.getPosition()` has enough time to return, but the second time around it does not. This is just a guess and I have not been able to confirm this.

I have also tried the following, but obviously that does not work, because `features` is not defined inside the arrow function. I am probably slightly stupid and it would easily be possible to pass the needed variables as arguments, but I could not figure out how.

```
geolocation.on('change:position', () => {
    while (k<whileDis){
    var current_pos = geolocation.getPosition();
    console.log(current_pos);
    
    var imbiss_pos = [features[k].getProperties().long, features[k].getProperties().lat];

    var calc_dist = getDistance(current_pos, imbiss_pos);
    console.log(calc_dist)
    if (calc_dist <= distance){
        console.log(String(features[k].getProperties().rating)+"behalten")
        tempDis.push(features[k])
    }
    k++
}
```

So if anyone could help me out here I would be really grateful.

Comment: OpenLayers geolocation is simply a wrapper for the JavaScript geolocation API.  If the device has not yet responded to a request or does not get a fix the position will be undefined.

Comment: So how would I make it wait there to get a position?

Comment: Having no position available is something any geolocation application should handle itself.  There may be no GPS satellite signal deep inside a building or in a vehicle driving through a tunnel.